# Tinymce: Create a custom Toolbar outside of the editor as shown in the diagram

Tags: tinymce, text-editor, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-5

[Please click on the link to view the UX I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjTCJ.png)

I need some direction on how do I go about achieving the above. The idea is to show the plus icon next to cursor and user can easily click on it and insert items of their choice. I feel it's a great UX!

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.setContent()` method to programmatically add content to the editor:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce.dom/tinymce.dom.selection/#setcontent
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editor/#setcontent

Here is a Tiny Fiddle demonstration:
http://fiddle.tinymce.com/5vhaab

In that Fiddle, I have also disabled the `menubar` and `toolbar` by setting them to `false`.
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#menubar
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/editor-appearance/#toolbar

Additionally, you can programmatically trigger other editor commands from outside of the editor itself using the `.execCommand()` method:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.editorcommands/#execcommand

Here is a list of available commands:
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/advanced/editor-command-identifiers/

Comment: Yes, i have implemented something similar already. Thanks, this gives me validation that I am on the right path. However, what I really need to do is always keep the plus icon that opens the dropdown next to the cursor. Any idea how can I go about that? It's very similar to the quickinsert however quickinsert keeps showing unless the user has focused out